# Twilio - [PHP] Error: [HTTP 400] Unable to create record: Invalid 'To' Phone Number: +9198XXXXXXXX

Tags: php, twilio

I am using PHP 8.2.4.
Here is my sample code to send sms and this is a trial account.

```
<?php
// Required if your environment does not handle autoloading
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Your Account SID and Auth Token from console.twilio.com
$sid = "ACXXXXXX";
$token = "fXXXXXXX";

// Initialize Twilio client
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

// Remove the plus sign and spaces from the phone number
$toNumber = '+9198XXXXXXXX'; // Corrected format

try {
    // Use the Client to make requests to the Twilio REST API
    $client->messages->create(
        $toNumber,
        [
            // A Twilio phone number you purchased at https://console.twilio.com
            'from' => '+9198XXXXXXXX', // Corrected format
            // The body of the text message you'd like to send
            'body' => "Hey Jenny! Good luck on the bar exam!"
        ]
    );

    echo "Message sent successfully.";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

I am trying to send sms to the same phone number.
I mean from and to numbers both are same. I am getting this error
`Error: [HTTP 400] Unable to create record: Invalid 'To' Phone Number:+9198XXXXXXXX`.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `// Remove the plus sign and spaces from the phone number` What is that about? `$toNumber` still has a `+` in it, have you tried removing it?

Comment: @brombeer, Yes I tried by removing `+` . Still getting the same error

Comment: The $toNumber and the sender number `from` may be the same. you should use two different phone numbers - one as the sender ('from' number) and another as the recipient ($toNumber)  @user3408779

Comment: Might this be something as simple as Twilio rejecting to allow sending texts to their own account numbers?